# Plotting Percentage rather than Density

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to mimic density plots with percentage, but unforunately having difficulty finding the right format. I have provided the code below trying to mimic density plots using percentage.

```
p <- 
  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y = ..count../sum(..count..))) + 
   #geom_density() alpha=.4, stat = 'bin', binwidth = "3000", position = "identity", fill="grey",cex = 0.8) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(x=mpg, y=..count../sum(..count..)), colour="black", fill="white", cex = 0.8)+
  #geom_density( stat = "density", position = "identity", fill="grey",cex = 0.8) 
  geom_density(stat = 'bin', position = "identity", fill="grey",cex = 0.8)  

p
```

[image]

Trying to get the bins to be similar to a density with curvatures. But using density, it provides the plot below:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option that may be appropriate is the `..density..` special variable and then `percent_format` from `scales`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), position = "identity",
                 colour="black", fill="white", cex = 0.8) +
  geom_density(fill="grey",cex = 0.8, alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format(accuracy = 1))
```

[image]